# The fastest way to connect to a known BLE device with firemonkey

Tags: delphi, bluetooth-lowenergy, firemonkey

the examples I have seen of BLE connection with Delphi / Firemonkey always start with a search for devices, then go to a service discovery to only then do the pairing.
This entire process takes about 5 seconds. I wonder if there is a faster way to connect to an already known device with known services and quickly send a command.

Comment: The answer depends on OS. And any way you need third-party library.

Comment: I'm targeting Android and iOS platforms.